# Model Containing List of Models (MVC-3, Razor)

Tags: model, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This problem has been plaguing me for two days now.  There are some similar posts, but none that address my problem completely.

Using MVC-3, Razor syntax:

-- EDIT.cshtml --

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "My", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <!-- Some fields... -->
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.LongDescription)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LongDescription)
    </div>

    <!-- Some more fields work... Including picture upload (summary).-->
    <input name="button" type="submit" value="Add Picture" />

    <!-- Picture Item display -->
    @foreach(var thumbnail in Model.ThumbnailImagePathAndNames) 
    {
      <img src="@Url.Content(@thumbnail.ThumbnailPicturePath)" alt="" width="200" />
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(o=>o.SelectedImage, @thumbnail.ImageGUID)  Primary Picture 
      <!-- Checkbox to mark for deletion -->
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(o=>thumbnail.Delete) Delete ???????? <!---- Here is a problem - I don't understand how this should work -->
    }
    <input id="Submit1" name="button" type="submit" value="Complete Edit!" />
}
```

-- MyController.cs --

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Edit(String button, HttpPostedFileBase file, MyMainModel model)
 {
     // if button = submit picture,  work with picture here and break(long story)

     // save model data
         // if valid, save and redirect


     // not valid or error, load up view like normal but with error messages
     model.LoadThumbnails();
     return View(model);

 }
```

-- MyMainModel.cs --

```
public class MyMainModel
{
    // some properties...
     public Guid? SelectedImage { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Detailed Description")]
    public String LongDescription { get; set; }

    // some more properties....


    // and finally my list of models
    public IList<ThumbnailModel> ThumbnailImagePathAndNames { get; set; }

    public void LoadThumbnails()
    {
         // load up initial thumbnail models
         this.ThumbnailImagePathAndNames = new List<ThumbnailModel>(readDataService.GetThumbnailModels(this.SomeID));
    }
}
```

-- ThumbnailModels.cs --

```
public class ThumbnailModel
{
    public Guid ImageGUID { get; set; }
    public String FullSizePicturePath { get; set; }
    public String ThumbnailPicturePath { get; set; }

    public bool Delete { get; set; }
}
```

So whats the problem?  Well, when the "Complete Edit!" button is pressed, the MyController's Edit is called, as expected with all the MyMainModle's data in tact.... except for the list of ThumbnailModel's - those turn out to be null.

How is this supposed to be done?  I have tried many different approaches to this including making an editable template and using EditFor(o=>... all to no avail (this became confusing as I didn't know if the EditFor was supposed to be for the entire collection or just a single item in the collection - I tried both ways).  All used to work until I added the complexity of the checkbox for deletion, therefore needing to retrieve the list of ThumbnailModels to check that internal Delete property value.

Thank you all for reading and trying to understand this.

[Disclaimer - some variable and method names have been changed to protect the innocent program.  A lot of code has been stripped away and replaced by comment code.]

Comment: Shouldn't that be `thumbnail=>thumbnail.Delete`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here's an example that I've put to illustrate some concepts:

Model:

```
public class MyMainModel
{
    public Guid? SelectedImage { get; set; }
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ThumbnailModel> ThumbnailImagePathAndNames { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}

public class ThumbnailModel
{
    public Guid ImageGUID { get; set; }
    public bool Delete { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyMainModel
        {
            // TODO: fetch from the repository instead of hardcoding
            ThumbnailImagePathAndNames = new[] 
            {
                new ThumbnailModel { ImageGUID = Guid.NewGuid() },
                new ThumbnailModel { ImageGUID = Guid.NewGuid() },
                new ThumbnailModel { ImageGUID = Guid.NewGuid() },
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyMainModel model) 
    {
        ... the model will be properly bound here
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model AppName.Models.MyMainModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.LongDescription)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LongDescription)
    </div>
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <!-- Use different names for the upload and complete submit
         buttons so that you can distinguish which one was clicked
         in the POST action 
    -->
    <input name="upload" type="submit" value="Add Picture" />

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ThumbnailImagePathAndNames)    
    <input name="complete" type="submit" value="Complete Edit!" />
}
```

Editor template: (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/ThumbnailModel.cshtml`):

```
@model AppName.Models.ThumbnailModel
<!-- Pass the image id as hidden field -->
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ImageGUID)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Delete)
```

Comment: Excellent!  It works!! Thank you so much - that is extremely helpful.  The last thing I'm trying to get to work with this example is that I have a somewhat more complex layout for each of the ThumbnailModels.  In my original code, I use something like @foreach (var thumbnail in Model.ThumbnailImagePathAndNames)...  It seems like I can't put my layout (column limit stuff) code around the edit for and and then use @Html.EditorFor(x => thumbnail).  Do you know how I could get this fine-grained control?  In the template somehow put @model IEnumerable<SVS.Models.ThumbnailModel> at the top?  Thanks!

Comment: ** I may have to move the above question to a new thread.  To paraphrase, I would like to have more control over @Html.EditorFor, using my own @Foreach handling each model separately, rather than letting .NET loop through and render it automatically.  Changing the editor template to take a @model IEnumerable<SVS.Models.ThumbnailModel> and implementing the @foreach within has proven unsuccessful.

Comment: @Rob, I don't understand what kind of control you need to have. In your example you are just looping through the collection and for each element you output a couple of input fields. EditorFor should be enough to avoid you writing all this.

Comment: Hi Darin, Originally (the code was stripped to simplify the example), I was keeping track of column and row counts and changing DIV styles depending on what row and column I was on in the @Foreach.  However, I discovered that wasn't the best solution and decided to take a slightly different approach with DIVs.  Now my formatting works as expected with the @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ThumbnailImagePathAndNames) you outlined above... as a result, my code is much cleaner and easier to understand.  Thanks so much again for taking the time to explain this!

Comment: Clean code always helps to solve problems that are similar to the original question. Thank you @DarinDimitrov