# Model with List - approaches to add new item to the list from a Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model with various properties but the one of interest is a List of another type of Model.

For example:

```
   public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<UserInterest> Interests { get; set; }
    }
```

I then use an Editor Template within my view to render out a view for each item of the model items.

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Interests)
```

The EditorFor template looks something like:

```
@model Interest

<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.InterestText)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Delete)
   ....
</div>
```

Something very similar to the accepted answer here: [Model Containing List of Models (MVC-3, Razor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720330/model-containing-list-of-models-mvc-3-razor)

My question is - how would you from the client-side (jQuery) create a new item within the property without going back to the server. I currently have a rough way of doing it whereby I post the data back to my controller which returns the model back with a new blank item within the Interests property.

This seems to be overkill making a HTTP request and not very elegent. I was thinking of using jQuery .Clone() but not entirely sure on what I'd need to do in terms of naming the elements and clearing existing values.

So does anybody have any suggestions. I'm hoping to get more opinions and different approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such situations I prefer to use client templating. You send data to server with ajax and then receive `JsonResult`. Look at [JsRender](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/demos.html) this is javascript lib without jQuery dependency.

Comment: Thanks - I've not considered using templating since jquery-tmpl was dropped.

Comment: @DaveHogan There are a large number of other libraries, I think that it is a crime to use PartialView, too much extra traffic used in the preparation of lists. Although, if project is small you can add data manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create the Textbox and checkbox on the fly and add that to the DOM. When saving it, Use jQuery ajax to post that data ( new record data) to an action method and save it there. Return a status back (Succcess /Falied) from your action method to your client side code ( your callback function of jQuery ajax/post) and check it there. If it is success, Show a success message to the user and `append` the new item to the existing list.

Sample jSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/carwB/2/

If you want to return some complex data ( ex : All new records with its id etc..) along with the status, you may return `JSON` from your action method.

**EDIT :** To keep your Model binding works with the newly added dynamic elements, you need to follow the naming convention of the elements.

The trick is to keep the id property value of the html element in this format.
**CollectionName_*ItemIndex*__PropertyName**

and name property value in this format

**CollectionName[*ItemIndex*].PropertyName**

I created a sample working program and explained it how it works [Here](http://www.techiesweb.net/asp-net-mvc3-dynamically-added-form-fields-model-binding/) based on your requirements.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the default model binder doesn't pick up the new posted elements? I assume because of the duplicate IDs?

Comment: if you keep the name property model binder may pick it (not sure)

Comment: +1 - Thanks @Shyju - I've accepted webdeveloper's answer but yours has also been very helpful

Answer (score 1):

1.Create two partial view one is for list item and second one is creation

2.First partail view should be inside the div which has id 'divMdeolList'

3.and Creation view will have the code like that

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubmitData", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divMdeolList" }))
{
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.InterestText)
  <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
  </p>
}
```

4. And then create a ActionResult type action on controller that will render the partialview

```
public ActionResult SubmitData(YourModel model)
{  
  //Do : save the record 
  return PartialView("FirstPartailView", model);
}
```

This will update the View without postback